# C# - How to retrieve a reference to an object from a combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm populating a ComboBox in C# from an instance of a class.
How to get the selected item by retrieving the reference to the corresponding object ? 
I already used SelectedValue, SelectedItem, SelectedIndex but they all return the string representation of my object..

Thanks

[EDIT]

A piece of code, to show what I'm trying to do :

The populating part:

```
foreach (Business.IAuteur auteur in _livreManager.GetAuthors())
            {
                comboAuthor.Items.Add(auteur);
            }
```

The retrieving part, activated when clicking on the save button :

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Business.IAuteur auteur = new Business.Auteur();

            auteur = (Business.IAuteur)comboAuthor.SelectedValue;

            // A short verification that my item has been correctly
            // retrieved
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = auteur.Nom;
        }
```

The error message, pointing here: toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = auteur.Nom;

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Comment: Please show how you are adding the items to the combobox. Naturally if you add strings to it, you'll only get strings back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) is returning a `string` object, then you are populating your ComboBox with strings.  If you override `ToString` in your POCOs, the ComboBox will automatically display that value while returning the desired object with `SelectedItem`.

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx), you should also override `Equals` in your POCO so it can be found in the Items collection if necessary.

**EDIT:**  Addressing your code.
Lose the `.ToString()` call when adding to the ComboBox and follow my advice above.

Comment: Ok it's working, with SelectedItem. No need to override Equals after all!
Thanks !

Comment: If you ever want to *set* the SelectedItem, you will need to override Equals.  I tend to do that as a habit now just to avoid surprises in the future.